# Why the query statement cannot be executed when filtering the jumped data from high to low in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to query the changing data of `s1` signal, it can be successfully queried. However, when I tried to filter the jump data from high to low using `select s1 from root.db.ss.v1 where (time between now() - 1d and now()) and difference(s1) > 0` command, an error will be reported and the query cannot be executed. Anyone know where should I change my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command you mentioned,you use 'difference' function,but in Apache IoTDB this should be write as 'DIFF' function if you wangt to query the jump value of 's1' signal.